# How to wake from screensaver directly to the login screen in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.10, screensaver, login-screen

*(a.k.a. How to switch users without entering password, part II) (see [part I](https://superuser.com/questions/119254))*

I've got Ubuntu 9.10 with a user account for my wife, and one for myself. "Wake-from-screensaver" should result in "choose user" **without** having to enter any password. I know how to do that in Windows, but I'm not good with Linux (yet).

Part of this was answered in [my earlier question](https://superuser.com/questions/119254) which helped me get past the login screen without passwords (after booting, and after choosing "switch user"), but once the screensaver kicks in and I wake it up again, the system does not present the "choose user" screen. Instead, it either turns off the screensaver and presents the desktop of the most recent user, or (if the screensaver is set to lock the screen) prompt for the user's password (which can be handily surpassed by clicking the "switch user" button and choosing the same user again).

So, the login ("choose user") screen has been dealt with. **How do I make the (any) screensaver return to the login screen at wake, rather than to the current user's desktop?** Windows can do this, I'm sure Linux can too - but how?

Comment: So you are logged in. The screensaver kicks in. You want to wake up on the login screen and not be logged in anymore? Because if it is, I'd rather title this *"How to wake from screensaver directly to the login screen"* instead. For switching users without entering password I suppose you just set the screensaver to lock screen and click on the "switch user" so you're directed to the login screen. The "entering password" or not is not a matter of discussion, as far as I understand this question.

Comment: @Cawas: it's not really the best title to describe the current situation, is it?  i think that's fixable...

Answer (score 2):

You're making a habit of weird tweaks, aren't you?

Anyway, this one is weird, but interesting.  I'm sorry to say I don't have a complete solution, but I found a couple of interesting items that warrant a response.  They may give you some ideas of where to go from here.

- [Gnome-Screensaver's FAQ](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Is_there_a_way_to_perform_actions_when_the_screensaver_activates_or_deactivates.3F__Or_when_the_session_becomes_idle.3F) indicates that the screensaver emits a DBus signal when the session's idle status changes:

  > Is there a way to perform actions when the screensaver activates or deactivates? Or when the session becomes idle?
  >
  > One way is to watch for the D-Bus signals from gnome-screensaver. (...)

  The FAQ provides an example *dbus-monitor* command:

  ```
  dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver',member='SessionIdleChanged'"
  ```

  Although I believe the *interface* and *member* details are outdated for Ubuntu 9.10; the proper values seem to be *[interface=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Session](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/ConsoleKit/doc/ConsoleKit.html#Session)* and *member=IdleHintChanged*.  (See the [ConsoleKit documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/ConsoleKit/doc/ConsoleKit.html).)

  When the screensaver lock is enabled, the *IdleHintChanged* signal is emitted *after* the password is entered successfully into the unlock dialogue.
- The command *gdmflexiserver -xnest* can be used from the commandline to get back to the login screen.  It works within your X session by itself, but you can use *dbus-launch* to execute it from, say, an SSH session:

  ```
  DISPLAY=:0 dbus-launch gdmflexiserver -xnest
  ```

  That "activates" the GDM login screen, without logging the current user session out, just like the *"Switch User..."* menu option does (at least as far as I can tell).

The trick will be to find some way to glue these two together.  It seems to me that what you'd want to do is basically:

1. Disable the screensaver's lock;
2. Register a listener with DBus that listens for the *IdleHintChanged* signal on all sessions;
3. Have the listener execute the *gdmflexiserver* command when it detects the signal.

Step 1 is needed so you don't get the password prompt.  If step 2 works properly and step 3 kicks off, you'll get the login window anytime your system comes out of the screensaver.  But step 2 is what I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: if i come up with something clever for step 2 i'll edit it in, but this may give you something to work on in the meantime.

Comment: On the mac, when you lock the screen there's an option to "change user" which goes to login screen by default. If the other user have no password, you can unlock the screen without needing one. This is not a weird question at all.

Comment: @Cawas: yeah, that's not an especially serious statement.

Comment: I don't think this is a weird tweak. I'm surprised that a multi-user system like Linux doesn't have that feature built-in since forever. Especially considering that both Mac OS and Windows have this feature. I'm also surprised that the solution is so roundabout, but then again I'm just a simple user with no programming experience; perhaps it's the best solution this way.

Comment: Now I don't know what to do about the bounty. I guess I'll accept this answer, but I feel unable to really try if it works. I thought there would be a setting "in there somewhere" to trigger what I want. Thank you for your very elaborate explanation!

Comment: @torbengb: don't accept this if you're not sure it's what you want! currently accepted answers are permanent on bounty questions.  though, if the bounty expires, you lose the ability to accept an answer at all.  (bounties are tricky things!)  you've still got a couple of days before the bounty expires; maybe wait another day to see if a more direct solution gets posted.

Comment: This is the first bounty I've given; I was hesitant because exactly this situation could arise... I'll wait a bit for more answers, but then I'll have to "tick" the one that seems the most promising.

Comment: @quack I'm pretty sure you were trying to dominate the world with that statement, in some evil plot that must evolve a microwave and a shaving cream!

Comment: @Cawas: only insofar as i will first Shave all unicorns and finally Microwave them!  _*muahahahaha!*_

Comment: @quackquixote is it possible to use the command `dbus-launch gdmflexiserver -xnest` with another command to turn the display off simultaneosly? I wrote a bash script and used `xset dpms force off` but the display stays on.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this question is for years ago, but some users may be still searching for this.

One may prefer Ubuntu login screen to lock screen at wake (for example not to show even the wallpaper on an encrypted home), and this is possible in Ubuntu 12.10 and 13.04 (not sure about earlier versions).

So to do this, open **Dconf Editor** (pre-installed on Ubuntu 12.10+) and go to:

**org** > **gnome** > **desktop** > **screensaver**

Enter the command  `dbus-launch gdmflexiserver -xnest` for the variable *embedded-keyboard-command*. Then check *embedded-keyboard-enabled* for the same schema.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to provide my own answer here, which is that there apparently is no (easy) solution to what I'm asking for.

A solution *potentially* exists but it is not complete and requires deep Linux understanding - as can be seen in the first answer. So it's not an out-of-the-box answer I would feel right about accepting as "the" answer.

**Question:**

> How do I make the (any) screensaver return to the login screen at wake, rather than to the current user's desktop?

**Answer: You can't.**