# How to switch user in putty Login windows

Tags: putty

```
login as: hnb
hnb@119.29.58.95's password:
Access denied
hnb@119.29.58.95's password:
```

I always make a mistake to input the local server's username, so I have to close the putty login window.
What I want to know is whether there is a way to switch user after I input the wrong username. Thanks a lot.

Comment: While it's technically possible with SSHv2, most servers don't actually allow it even if PuTTY could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below screenshots :
[image]
[image]

I am not sure. But I think it appears when server interrupts the connection.

Comment: right clike the head of the panel . If the current login is offline , then there will have restart session selection , or there are new session, duplicate session and  save session. Thank you so much from my sincerely heart.

Answer (score 0):

Made a new putty link and after the destination executable add this

```
-ssh -l [yourusernamewithoutbrackets]
```

example:

[image]

so will never be wrong with username again.